# Unable to open Edge (Chromium) profile with selenium (4.0.0)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, chromium

I tried the following code to open the pre existing profile.

```
from selenium import webdriver
option = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
option.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\Default')
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=option)
driver.get('http://www.youtube.com')
```

Edge opens with the new profile and the result is same as the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('http://www.youtube.com')
```

I even ensure the profile path by going into 'edge://version/'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to make the below change may help you to start the Edge with the default profile.

```
option.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data')
```

You can see that I have passed **User Data** instead of **Default**.

You can test this suggestion on your end and let us know about your test results.

Comment: I test the code on my side with selenium 4.0 and it is launching the default profile properly. Can you try to access the path for the default profile and launch the browser from that location? See which profile it shows. It may help to narrow down the issue.