# User profile on Edge using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

Everytime I open edge using selenium , it opens with a new profile. How to set my own profile?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497618/unable-to-open-edge-chromium-profile-with-selenium-4-0-0)maybe helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below to open Edge with specific profile:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True    

#Here you set the path of the profile ending with User Data not the profile folder
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data"); 

#Here you specify the actual profile folder    
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1");

edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = "your\\path\\to\\edge\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

The above code uses **MS Edge Selenium tools**. You need to run the command below to install it:

```
pip install msedge-selenium-tools selenium==3.141
```

Please note to change all the paths in the code to your owns. If you don't know the path of the specific profile, you could check **edge://version/** like below:

[image]

Comment: from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge,EdgeOptions
edge_options = EdgeOptions()

edge_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\trojan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data')
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = "C:\\Program Files\\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

Comment: [5268:11912:0531/155451.069:ERROR:profile_manager.cc(990)] Cannot create profile at path C:\Users\trojan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default

Comment: Please make sure the profile path is right. Please make sure the Edge WebDriver version is the same as Edge browser version. Besides, which version of selenium are you using? I found that you missed this line: `edge_options.use_chromium = True` and you need to use link with protocal like this: `driver.get('https://google.com')`. And if you want to use the Default profile, you can remove this line: `edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")`. Please try the above to see if they can fix the issue.

Comment: Dodgy semicolon on this line: edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1");